# CuratorFramework spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

So if I have 2 services, A and B. Each service implements CuratorFramework, but access the same Zookeeper cluster.

Now these are spring boot applications. Once i run these spring boot apps, fire some requests at it, over a period of time my service started throwing OutOfMemory: Unable to create new native thread. So i did a thread dump and i noticed the following:

```html
Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0 - priority:5 - threadId:Curator-ConnectionStateManager-0 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager.processEvents(ConnectionStateManager.java:245)
org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager.access$000(ConnectionStateManager.java:43)
org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager$1.call(ConnectionStateManager.java:111)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me as i am not sure why these threads are waiting

Thanks,

Comment: That thread is normal. Curator has a thread dedicated to processing background tasks, etc. So, there's nothing wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for the quicky reply. But what isnt normal is to have 300+ of these threads spawning and waiting. I was able to see this through jvisual that was attached to my service. As a result it went over the thread limit set on the jvm

Comment: That suggests you have 100s of CuratorFramework instances as there is only 1 ConnectionStateManager per CuratorFramework.